# Unable to compile IDL file, error MIDL2020

Tags: c++, com, atl, midl

I'm trying to create a COM component (C++, with ATL), my goal is to derive from the [ITsSbPlugin interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sbtsv/nn-sbtsv-itssbplugin).

I'm stuck at the very beginning: I'm not able to compile my IDL file, with MIDL (Version 8.01.0626)...

MIDL shows this error:

`midl\oleaut32.dll : error MIDL2020 : error generating type library : LayOut failed : ITsSbTarget (0x80029C83)`
0x80029C83 is the error code for "Inconsistent property functions"

The error won't show if I remove this from the `library` section in my IDL file:

```cpp
[
    uuid("37f1f870-3c5d-4a21-b515-034543f2c411")
]
coclass TestModule
{
    [default] interface ITestModule;
};
```

My IDL file:

```cpp
// TestModule.idl : IDL source for TestModule
//

// This file will be processed by the MIDL tool to
// produce the type library (TestModule.tlb) and marshalling code.

import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";
import "unknwn.idl";
import "sbtsv.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid("193a132b-2aed-4be9-a222-1b1b13ec9dd5")
]
interface ITestModule : ITsSbPlugin
{
    HRESULT Initialize(
        ITsSbProvider* pProvider,
        ITsSbPluginNotifySink* pNotifySink,
        ITsSbPluginPropertySet* pPropertySet
    );

    HRESULT Terminate(HRESULT hr);
};


[
    uuid("d09d55ae-9bf3-44d4-ad46-22c6144ab4a8"),
    version(1.0)
]
library TestModuleLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
        uuid("37f1f870-3c5d-4a21-b515-034543f2c411")
    ]
    coclass TestModule
    {
        [default] interface ITestModule;
    };
};
```

I don't understand what this error means, what can I do to properly compile this IDL?

Comment: MIDL errors are often quite poor, the real problem is that a type library can only store interfaces that derive from either IUnknown or IDispatch.  First check if you actually need a type library, next consider encapsulation.

Comment: The problem is your idl tries to embed sbtsv.idl content into TestModule.tlb (interfaces, etc.) but sbtsv.idl is not designed to be embarked into a type library, only to produce a .h. Definitions such as ITsSbTarget::get/put_IpAddresses are invalid for a type library. What you can just do is define ITestModule to derive from IUnknown in your idl, and implement ITsSbPlugin in your ATL class. ie: forget about sbtsv references in your .idl.

Comment: @SimonMourier ITsSbPlugin needs ITsSbProvider, ITsSbPluginNotifySink, ITsSbPluginPropertySet, and one thing leading to another I'll need to implement almost every definitions of sbtsv.idl

Comment: Yes, of course. I told you to remove all references of sbtsv.idl in your idl - you don't have the choice - but to use sbtsv.h normally in your ATL project h & cpp files.